# Formatting of hangindent with 2 columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, indentation

I've been trying to produce the following output:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\hangindent=6cm
\hangafter=1
\noindent Fall 2017\\
Matrix Algebra\\
Matrix Algebra\\

\hangindent=6cm
\hangafter=1
\noindent Summer 2017\\
Geometry\\
History of Mathematics

\end{document}
```

But this produces the following:

[image]

Can anyone suggest some easy fix? I tried to solve the problem with \flushright and \hfill, but I don't want the name of the subject to go all the way to the right. Instead, I want the names of the subjects to start more or less 6cm from the left margin. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tabular as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}l}
Fall 2017 & Matrix Algebra\\
 & Matrix Algebra\\[0.25cm]
Summer 2017 & Geometry\\
 & History of Mathematics
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As tabular columns always have some additional white space on their left and right, you might consider removing these spaces to let the text in the second column start 6 cm right of the left margin. The following example shows this approach (using `@{}` to get rid of the white space)  in comparison to the result from the above MWE. The vertical lines show the margins and result from the `showframe` package, while the short horizontal line shows the distance of 6cm from the left margin.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}l}
Fall 2017 & Matrix Algebra\\
 & Matrix Algebra\\[0.25cm]
Summer 2017 & Geometry\\
 & History of Mathematics
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{6cm}@{}@{}l}
Fall 2017 & Matrix Algebra\\
 & Matrix Algebra\\[0.25cm]
Summer 2017 & Geometry\\
 & History of Mathematics
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case your second column contains text that is too wide to fit in one line, you might also consider using the `tabularx` package. A MWE using this package would be the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}X}
Fall 2017 & Matrix Algebra\\
 & Matrix Algebra\\[0.25cm]
Summer 2017 & Geometry\\
 & History of Mathematics
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

`X` in this case stands for a flexible width column that takes up as much horizontal space as it is needed to make the table as wide as `\textwidth`. It also allows for automatic linebreaks of too long contents.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I have one small question: what's the exact meaning of {p{6cm}l}? Does it mean 6cm to the right from the first column? Or does it mean 6cm to the right from the left margin? In other words, what does "p" mean and what does "l" mean here?

Comment: `p` is a tabular column that can have a specified width (in this case 6cm). `l` stands for a column that is left aligned and as wide as its widest contents.

Comment: @Pawel: You're welcome. I have extended my answer to include some more details on  the width of tabular columns.

Comment: Thank you! Also, when you said "while the short vertical line shows the width of 6cm," did you mean "the horizontal line?"

Comment: @Pawel: Sorry, of course it is the horizontal line that indicates a distance of 6cm from the left margin.